# .htaccess giving rewrite resulting in 404

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

am trying to get this simple RewriteRule to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^agb$ download/AGB.pdf$ [L]
RewriteRule ^impr$ impressum$ [L]
```

The file exists, and I can open it, if I manually open the url.

Now I have two problems with this.

1. The agb rule leads to a 404
2. The impr rule works (funny, as it has the same syntax as the agb rule), but it doesn't mask the url, it just changes it in the browser. Shouldn't the entered url stay the same, masked, not for the user to see, that there is some other URL behind it?

Many thanks.

*edit:

After following the advice to remove the $, I started playing around with the impr rule. Seems that the rule is not making the redirects, but wordpress is. Very try from /i over /imp to /impressu leads to the /impressum site. My bad, I didn't see this.

*edit:

The full file, as requested, looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^agb$ download/AGB.pdf$ [L]
RewriteRule ^impr$ impressum$ [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Remove those trailing `$` chars from the target paths. They do not make any sense.

Comment: Since this is WP, can you show your full .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - when reading the comment arkascha postet AGAIN AND COMPLETELY, it really were those $ on the target path.

Thanks a lot!!!!